# Words not separeted by commas when writing to CSV

Tags: java, export-to-csv, printwriter

Code successfully writes to CSV but writes every line in one cell.

For example:

```
hămăit, hămăit, SUBST, 98226, 98226, null, ron, n
hămăit, hămăit, SUBST, 2, 98226, nom-sg, ron, n
```

The example above is divided correctly into lines, but each line is just one cell, not separated by commas.

This is how the text looks before being written to the csv:

```
[hămăit, hămăit, SUBST, 98226, 98226, null, ron, {{n}}, hămăit, hămăit, SUBST, 2, 98226, nom-sg, ron, {{n}}, ...
```

Below is my code.

```
public String escapeSpecialCharacters(String data) {
   String escapedData = data.replaceAll("\\R", " ");
   escapedData = escapedData.replaceAll("\\{", "");
   escapedData = escapedData.replaceAll("}", "");
   return escapedData;
}

public String convertToCSV(WordDictObj data) {
   String[] strings = data.returnStringArray();
   return Stream.of(strings)
      .map(this::escapeSpecialCharacters)
      .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}

public void givenDataArray_whenConvertToCSV_thenOutputCreated() throws IOException {
   OutputStream csvOutputFile = new FileOutputStream("parseOutPut.csv");
   try (PrintWriter pw = (new PrintWriter(csvOutputFile, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
      dataLines.stream()
         .map(this::convertToCSV)
         .forEach(pw::println);

   }
}
```

I checked and it works fine both in google sheets and when viewed inside my IDE as a CSV (and I select comma as value separator). Apparently it's just in excel that it's not working. Also in excel it doesn't display special characters.

How it looks in google sheet:
[image: google sheet]

How it looks in notepad++:
[image: notepad]

How it looks in excel:
[image: excel]

Comment: *String escapedData = data.replaceAll("\\R", " ");* Why are you collapsing all the lines into *one* line?

Comment: what does the file  look like when opened in a text editor like vim or possibly notepad?

Comment: I don't use Excel proper, but you might need to tell it that it's UTF-8

Comment: @SIMULATAN I added links to some screenshots

Comment: @g00se oops, I was supposed to delete that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the notepad++ screenshot you attached, the lines look completely fine and, in fact, have a comma separating the fields. Also, google sheets seems to work just fine as well. Therefore, it's most likely an issue with excel.

As pointed out by g00se in the comments, it looks like you have to specify the encoding.